# Application Routes with Spring MVC

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-mvc, url-routing

I'm looking for a way to manage the route's use on my WebApp.
Basically, I have three places that could share a router pattern.
And I could send this pattern to use on my views, through expression language.

```
@Controller
public class LoginRuasController
{
    @RequestMapping("/system/index")
    public String logout(ModelMap model, HttpSession session)
    {
        return "system/index";
    }   

    @RequestMapping("/system/logout")
    public String logout(ModelMap model, HttpSession session)
    {
        session.setAttribute("xxx", null);
        return "redirect:/system/login";
    }
}
```

patterns:

```
/system/index
system/index
redirect:/system/login
```

views:

```
<a href="#{Routes.newuser}">Triple X</a>
```

Initially, RequestMapping requests a constant value, so this generate 
a problem to implement a Route class with static return.
Is there any solution available?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand, what do you mean exactly by saying `application routes`. P.S. After **can** or **could** don't put **to**, i.e. the right form is _could share_, not _could to share_.

Comment: The easy maintenance of the code is my objective.

Comment: Please attempt to reformulate your question. Your objective should be more clear. Every good developer's objective is to create maintainable code - Please describe your question with more specific examples.

Comment: It seems that what you're asking for is a way to refer to routes based on some other factor, such as controller/method name (like Rails allows). Is this correct?

Comment: @parsifal Yes, almost this. I wanna have a centered Routes management. Sample: all references to "http://mywepp.com/system/users" can be encountered on Routes. On Routes class, I wanna have a method that return it based on "destin" passed by param. So, calling by Routes.get("system_users"), then it will return the respective url.

Comment: The only problem consists to bind a value to @RequestMapping, I don't know how to pass a external value to it.

Comment: You can't. What you *can* do is create another annotation that contains your key, then use reflection on the list of beans to build your `Routes` object.

Comment: I found a solution, please comment about it.

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution, as follows:

1) I create a Routes class

```
public class Routes {

    private static HashMap<String, String> routes;

    public static final String host = "/mywebapp";
    public static final String home = "/home";
    public static final String login = "/login";
    public static final String logout = "/logout";

    private static void setRoutes()
    {       
        if(routes == null)
        {
            routes = new HashMap<String, String>();

            routes.put("host", host);
            routes.put("home", host + home);
            routes.put("entrar", host + entrar);
            routes.put("sair", host + sair);
        }
    }   

    public static HashMap<String, String> getRoutes()
    {
        setRoutes();

        return routes;
    }

    public static String getRoute(String destin)
    {
        setRoutes();

        return routes.get(destin);
    }

}
```

2) I use on my Controller... Now it's possible set a RequestMapping

```
@Controller
public class HomeController extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping(Routes.home)
    public String home(ModelMap model)
    {
        preRender(model);       
        return Routes.home;
    }

}
```

3) I set Routes to use on my views

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    protected void preRender(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("routes", Routes.getRoutes()); 
    }

}
```

4) And it's available now to use on the views

```
<body>
    <p>Mary is singing.</p>
    <p><a href="${routes.home}">Home</a></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Old question, I know, but for future searchers: you can also use a combination of `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ModelAttribute` to add a reference to the routes class to the model associated with every controller.

Comment: do you have an example?